# Select data from three tables using sub query and group by

Tags: sql-server

I would like to write a query for SQL Server to select “Sales” by “month” 
  (Sales from one table[sales_fact] and month from another table[time_by_day]) 
  where sales is grouped by  “ product_name"
  and it is again form another table[product] i.e. sales/product by month. Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    time_by_day.the_month , 
    ( SELECT sum(store_sales) 
      FROM sales_fact
        INNER JOIN product 
        ON  sales_fact.product_id = product.product_id
      GROUP BY product_name
    )
    AS total_sales 
FROM sales_fact 
  INNER JOIN time_by_day 
  ON  sales_fact.time_id = time_by_day.time_id
GROUP BY 
    time_by_day.the_month 
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(mm,CAST(the_month+ ' 1900'  AS DATETIME)) asc;
```

But it is not working. Getting error for the subquery. Can I get some advice pls?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: It would good to provide: the exact error message and the table definitions (CREATE TABLE) so we know the column types, what UNIQUE and FK constraints there are and which table each column belongs to (you haven't aliased `store_sales` for example and we have no idea which of the 3 tables it belongs to).

Comment: Please, can you clarify the aim of your query? Do you need total sales by month or total sales of products by month?

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery:

```
SELECT     sum(store_sales) 
FROM       sales_fact
INNER JOIN product 
ON         sales_fact.product_id = product.product_id 
GROUP BY   product_name
```

returns a list of aggregate sum by product.

But your main query expects only one value due you're grouping by month.

```
SELECT     time_by_day.the_month 
FROM       sales_fact 
INNER JOIN time_by_day 
ON         sales_fact.time_id = time_by_day.time_id
GROUP BY   time_by_day.the_month 
ORDER BY   DATEPART(mm,CAST(the_month+ ' 1900'  AS DATETIME)) asc;
```

SQL Server returns an error indicating that your subquery returns more than one value.

If you want aggregate sales by product, instead of a subquery, join your products table on your main query on this way:

```
SELECT     t.the_month,
           p.product_id,
           p.product_name, 
           sum(store_sales) as total_sales 
FROM       sales_fact 
INNER JOIN time_by_day 
ON         sales_fact.time_id = time_by_day.time_id
INNER JOIN product p
ON         s.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY   t.the_month, p.product_id. p.product_name 
ORDER BY   DATEPART(mm,CAST(t.the_month + ' 1900' AS DATETIME)) ASC;
```

However if you need total sales by month, remove `prduct.id` and `product.name` from both, SELECT and GROUP BY statements.

```
SELECT     t.the_month,
           sum(store_sales) as total_sales_month 
FROM       sales_fact 
INNER JOIN time_by_day 
ON         sales_fact.time_id = time_by_day.time_id
INNER JOIN product p
ON         s.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY   t.the_month 
ORDER BY   DATEPART(mm,CAST(t.the_month + ' 1900' AS DATETIME)) ASC;
```

If your time_by_day table has a datetime field, you can use it on your  ORDER BY clause instead of build a datetime value. In fact if you're filtering more than one year, actual ORDER BY clause do not work properly.

```
ORDER BY   time_by_day.date_field ASC;
```

If there is no datetime value, you can order by month without cast.

```
ORDER BY   t.the_month ASC;
```